# Spring + Hibernate + c3p0 + MySql does not timeout if connection to database fails

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, database-connection, c3p0

I am using a combination of Spring, Hibernate and Mysql with c3p0 for connection pooling. My problem is that, the application takes 15-20 minutes to deploy when the database connection parameters are wrong. (i faced this when I had given a wrong url for the database). Moreover, when I check my tomcat logs, I cannot see any exceptions.

The configurations I am using :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
             p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
             p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
             p:packagesToScan="com.cronos"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:acquireRetryAttempts="3"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10"/>
```

I need helping with the configuration, such that the application will timeout after a given period if it cannot connect to a database and throw some exception in the log.

Answer (score 0):

You can "store" the database connection in the tomcat context and make it avaiable via JNDI. So when need to change the configuration then you only need to restart the server, but must not redeploy the application.

@see [Tomcats How To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources)